# How to get rid off - sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins

Tags: apache2, cgi, ubuntu-12.04, sudo, sudoers

I am trying to configure apache2 with cgi (python). For that, I have to change permissions of some folders and files but I am getting sudo fatal errors every time I try to change permission of a file or a Folder.

For Example:

1

```
j@ubuntu:/etc/apache2$ ls

apache2.conf envvars magic mods-enabled sites-available

conf.d httpd.conf mods-available ports.conf sites-enabled



j@ubuntu:/etc/apache2$ sudo chmod 777 httpd.conf

sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner

sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

...................................................................................

2

```
j@ubuntu:/usr/lib/cgi-bin$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner

sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

...................................................................................

3

j@ubuntu:/usr/lib$ sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/cgi-bin

```
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner

sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

...................................................................................

Note:

j@ubuntu:/etc/apache2$ ls -l /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 177452 Jan 31 2012 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 4):

If you have docker installed on your host, you can leverage its permission vulnerabilities on volumes to solve this issue.

Run
`docker run -it -v /usr/lib/sudo:/tmp ubuntu:xenial`

Once inside the container, being the root user there, you can:

- `cd /tmp`
- `chown root sudoers.so` or `chmod 644 sudoers.so` depending on the exact issue

It's not a really clean solution but it solves the issue.

Comment: helped me after I `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/lib`

Answer (score 2):

You have to login to root shell to resolve this sudoers.so permission issue. If you have root account login, directly login to root shell otherwise search something like "How do I boot into a root shell" or "Drop to root shell prompt". If you use Ubuntu you can follow this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell.
Once you are in root shell change the permission of the file /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so to

```
#chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

Answer (score 0):

for OSX, there is diskutil command to repair disk permissions:

```
diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u`
```

it will take a while :(  ... you might first try to open script editor, create new script and execute:

```
do shell script "chown -R root /usr/local/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so" with administrator privileges
```

if that does not work, the repairpermission should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to login as a root user and change the file permission for the directory as

chmod 700 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so then it will solve your problem.

It worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
pkexec chmod go-w /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

Comment: Suggestions to try something don't belong in answers but in comments. Answers should consist of verified code that doesn't require confirmation. Please be aware of [Stack overflow's mission statement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384292/861716) when adding content.